Minimizing the infinity norm of a matrix
Let $v_1,\dots v_k$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^k$ and $d\ll k$. We want to find vectors $u_1,\dots u_d\subset \{v_1,\dots v_k\}$ in order to minimize
$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^d u_i u_i^\top\right\|_\infty,$$
or at least such that this quantity is at most $\rho>1$ times the optimum, where $\rho$ does not depend on $d,k$.

Is there any closed-form solution?
Is there any algorithm running in polynomial time for both $k,d$?

Notes
The infinity norm of a matrix can be viewed also as the maximal $1-$norm between its rows.
The $2-$norm of
$\sum_{i=1}^d u_i u_i^\top$ is one, as it is a projection matrix.
The problem would be easy if we had sub-modularity (as for knaspack), but I cannot show that this property holds (and I suspect it does not)
